# Change apollo local state whenever a remote mutation is called

Tags: react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm studying the usage of `Apollo Client` `Local State Management`, and came across this issue: I want to change my local state whenever a specific mutation is called.

From what I could read the only way would be writing to the cache or calling a `@client` mutation in every place that calls the remote mutation.

Is there a way to do that in one place and only call the remote mutation in all places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone gets here I solved by creating a local mutation that calls the server mutation and does whatever it wants as well:

```
resolver(parent, args, context) {
  // do anything else
  return context.client.mutate(...);
}
```